# Tomcat 7.1.1: Access denied

Tags: tomcat

I cannot login to the manager application for Tomcat 7.1.1. Even with the right credentials I always get a 403 Access Denied. What am I missing?

tomcat-users.xml:

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="admin1" password="password" roles="manager, admin"/>
  <user username="admin2" password="password" roles="manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case tomcat-users.xml file has been changed after tomcat had started, you may be trying to use not the actual user/password pairs. Re-starting tomcat should help in this case.

In case tomcat is started with `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` pointing to different directories, make sure you're looking into `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/tomcat-users.xml` file.

Also, make sure that access to the manager application is controlled by the `UserDatabaseRealm`, Otherwise, user/password info in this file is not effective. Search for the `<Realm/>` element in `CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml`.

There's also a probability that some other component may override/modify the `UserDatabse` JNDI resource, which normally reads user and role info from tomcat-users.xml for use by the `UserDatabaseRealm`. Search for `<Resource name="UserDatabase"/>` element in `CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml`.

You may also want to have a look at [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html) page in Tomcat documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I used the credentials used in tomcats guide on the 403 page and restart tomcat. The ball started rolling again, thank you.